# MySQL check if column contains words from String

Tags: java, mysql

Hi Im trying to make a keywords search for a java program I'm working on. I have run into a wall trying to work out how I can pass a string that contains 1-n words separated by spaces and then see if the column in the mysql database has any. If it contains at least one I want it to return the the selected data.

I have tried using the WHERE LIKE way of doing it but it doesnt seem to work

eg

```
SELECT `Data`
FROM `TABLE`
WHERE `Keywords` LIKE passedString
```

Comment: reverse the condition (i.e. test if passedString contains the "keywords") and use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr   or maybe you could use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 2):

Use %, it represents zero, one, or multiple characters.

```
SELECT `Data`FROM `TABLE`WHERE `Keywords` LIKE '%passedString%'
```

Comment: Will this split the passed string into characters? Or will they still be whole words?

Comment: I think so you got confused. It will return those rows which contains 'passedString' in 'Data' column.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT `Data` FROM `TABLE` WHERE `Keywords` LIKE + '%' + passedString + '%'
```

But before you have to split the passed String into single Strings (words) and run your query in  a loop until you find your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The `"%"` sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern.

```
SELECT Data
FROM TABLE
WHERE Keywords LIKE '%passedString%'
```

`%` A substitute for zero or more characters.